# Server timestamp using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, timestamp

I am working on a review/comment process and would like to be able to store each review/comment given by a user for another one in firebase, with each review/rating given at the same time being under the same timestamp. I was using the JS function new Date().getTime() initially, and this works fine, but to ensure that users can't tamper with the value (ie by changing the date on their computer) I would like to use firebase timestamp instead.

Now, I want the end product to be a map:

```
[chatStartTime] : {
   review : stars,
   time : chatStartTime
 }
```

Which I then incorporate into a firebase document using transaction.set(). Now the issue is the ChatStartTime, which is supposed to represent this timestamp. I have the code:

```
var chatStartTime = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

As an aside, I am also hoping to get:

```
var chatStartTimeDate = chatStartTime.toDate();
```

However chatStartTimeDate leads to an error – my understanding is that this is because chatStartTime is essentially "void" until it is added to a document; is there any way to get around this and use this function? Also, if I just use chatStartTime for both instances, I end up with a map on the database of the form:

```
[object Object] 
  review : 4.5
  time :
        .sv: "timestamp"
```

Where .sv is a string type. How can I solve this issue? I'd like the end result to look something like (for example)

```
 1579194722735
  review : 4.5
  time : 1579194722735
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` value is written on the server at time of write. So you can't get it before the write happens. However, you can get the `writeTime` from the response. This should give you what you're after. Alternately, you could read the document back out after you write it to fetch the timestamp (but that seems unnecessary).

```
myCollection
    .doc('foo')
    .create({ timestamp: FirebaseFirestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() })
    .then(result => {
      const serverTime: Date = result.writeTime.toDate();
    });
```